# Elevation contours from .JP2 / .J2W files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, lidar, contour, jpeg-2000

Is there a way in ArcGIS, Global Mapper, or CAD to generate elevation contours or any sort of surface data from a .JP2 file? I've never been provided this format before and our client is telling us this is a full LiDAR dataset. Can someone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Do you have a spatial analyst license? It has a Contour tool.

Comment: I do, I've run this tool and am not overly satisfied with the results. It's showing different terrain features against existing. Is this tool designed to work on a .jp2? I am completely unfamiliar with this file format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension has a Contour tool.

The tool works on a raster format which jp2 (Jpeg2) is.

If the raster is using a geographic coordinate reference system (CRS), you might try projecting it to a projected CRS like a UTM zone and see if that gives you better results.

While work is happening to update various algorithms to support the curved surface of a geographic CRS, many tools are designed to work on a Cartesian plane AKA a projected CRS.